# Empty combo box when editable is true

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to auto select the first element in a combo box:

```
final ComboBox selectStatus = new ComboBox();
        selectStatus.getItems().addAll(
            "Active",
            "Blocked",
            "Suspended"
        );

        selectStatus.getSelectionModel().select(0);
        selectStatus.setEditable(true);
```

But when I add editable=true the combo box is empty. Can I solve this problem somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this:

```
    //first set it editable
    selectStatus.setEditable(true);

    //then, set the value of the first item
    selectStatus.getSelectionModel().select(0);
```

When you set it editable the values displayed is cleared, so you have to set the value after set it editable.

See the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBoxBase.html#setEditable%28boolean%29).